# I want to design a receipt with custom styles and dynamic data on a button click in ReactJS before exporting it to PDF

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I want to generate a receipt with dynamic data on a button click in ReactJS then I want to export it to pdf on the same button click. I am looking for a package or a trick by which I can design the receipt. I have come across the JSPDF package but it is very difficult to set the page coordinates there.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJvZDWN_sNY

He does it by explaining how to create receive and download link codes in that video.